# Máquina de estado que localize as primeiras quebras de linha, em C

Tags: c, máquina-de-estado

Como fazer uma máquina de estado em C, usando comandos de decisão (`if`, `else`) para percorrer um buffer recebido da internet, byte a byte, no intuito de localizar as primeiras quebras de linhas (`\n\n`), e só então gravar o content? A parte do socket já está ok, falta apenas a máquina de estado

Comment: Basicamente com `switch case(estado)`

Comment: O que você tentou? Qual dificuldade você está tendo?

Comment: como diz o @Earendul: a maneira mais basica é com `switch`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1648098/25324 Nesta pergunta tens muitas outras maneiras de fazer máquinas de estado (ver outras respostas).

Comment: A conexão é feita através de um socket, e implementado no protocolo HTTP 1.0. O programa é operado por linha de comando e compilado sobre Linux. Ele  recebe como parâmetro uma URI completa e um nome de arquivo, e em seguida conecta no servidor, recupera a página e salva no arquivo informado.

Comment: Sim. O socket está ok.  Faltando apenas a parte da maquina, para encontrar e contar esses caracteres "\r\n\r\n". Assim eu identifico o começo do content, discartando todo o header http.

Comment: Ainda não está claro por que você acha que precisa de uma máquina de estados. Por que não dá pra usar algo como [`strtok`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) ou mesmo um simples laço `for`? Já tentou com alguma dessas abordagens?

Comment: O "Header HTTP" é constituído de algumas linhas e uma quebra de linha vazia no final. Cada linha possui uma string com seus respectivos \r\n.  E para conseguir contar esses caracteres de fim de linha + o \r\n\r\n da linha vazia, é preciso de uma maquina de estado, seja lá, de que forma ela for construida.  Valeu! Obrigado por comentar.

Comment: Eu havia mencionado o `strtok`, mas o que vai lhe servir é o [`strstr`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm). Veja esse exemplo no SOEN: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726077/split-string-through-strtok-in-c-language